# Why might our service that listens to Azure service bus queue using NetMessagingBinding stop receiving messages?

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-binding, azureservicebus

We have a WCF service that listens to an Azure servicebus queue using the NetMessagingBinding.  However we are finding that sometimes the service seems to stop being notified when messages  arrive, ie we see the queue build up but none of our instances process the messages.

If we then reboot the instances they immediately start receiving messages from the queue again.

The code which opens the WCF service in our worker role:

```
var endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ICacheKeyExchangeWithSession)))
{
    Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(baseAddress + QueueNames.Cache)), 
    Binding = new NetMessagingBinding(), 
};

var endpointBehavior = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior
{
    TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider(id, secret), 
};

endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(endpointBehavior);
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(DataService), new Uri[] { });
host.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint);
host.Open();
```

and we have no specific config in the app.config for the NetMessagingBinding:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="transportClientEndpointBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TransportClientEndpointBehaviorElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
  <bindingElementExtensions>
    <add name="netMessagingTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingTransportExtensionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </bindingElementExtensions>
  <bindingExtensions>
    <add name="netMessagingBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </bindingExtensions>
</extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How long does it take until the service stops being able to receive messages?

Comment: it depends it seems that sometimes it goes for a day sometimes after a few hours, sometimes it doesn't happen at all.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: @andymoose no sorry. The project got shelved before we had a resolution, and we just switched from wcf to using the azure messaging libraries instead - at Microsoft's recommendation as I recall

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, it sounds like you may be victim of your IIS configuration: you need to ensure iis isn't configured to automatically recycle your application pool that runs your app. If you don't also have application initialization configured in iis, your service won't restart automatically and resume processing messages